# Encoding a data structure based on TLV encoding

Tags: c++, encoding, tlv

I have to encode the parameters present inside a data structure based on X.690 encoding.
Suppose, my structure is:

```
struct Data_Struct
{
   parameter1
   parameter2
   parameter3
}
```

Some or all of these parameter may be having valid data, say, `parameter1` and `parameter3`.
Then I am supposed to encode only `parameter1` and `parameter3` using TLV encoding.
Do I have to follow a sequencial procedure to follow this. Like,

```
Check whether parameter 1 is present
    If present, find the tag of the parameter from a lookup table and encode it
Check whether parameter 2 is present
    If present, find the tag of the parameter from a lookup table and encode it
Check whether parameter 3 is present
    If present, find the tag of the parameter from a lookup table and encode it
```

- As the procedure is repetitive can I modularize it?
- What will be the best way to do it?
- Is there any way to access the parameters sequentially?
- How can I have a relationship between the parameter and it's tag?

Length of the value is variable.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a table which holds pairs of members and tags, like `{&Data_Struct::parameter1, TagForParam1}`. This is unavoidable as the compiler cannot guess that tag.

You also need to define what you consider "empty" or "valid data". That probably depends on the type. E.g. is `+INF` a valid float value? So, add overloaded functions `bool IsValid(T)`

You can now write a generic routine that walks through the table, retrieves each paramter, checks if it's valid, and write it to your output stream.

A slight challenge here is that the type of `&Data_Struct::parameter1` may differ from `&Data_Struct::parameter2`; so your table must hold it via a wrapper, pointer to a base class, or something similar.